# Connection string not found WebSecurity.IntializeDatabaseConnection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

In a test project I'm using SimpleMembershipProvider and Entity Framework 5. The test project creates a database using localdb, and out of the blue it stopped working. I'm not sure what changed, but I'm stumped. This is pretty much boilerplate:

```
    private static void InitializeSimpleMembership()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestEfhContext>(null);
        using (var context = new TestEfhContext(ConnectionString))
        {
            if (!context.Database.Exists())
            {
                // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
            }

            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(ConnectionString, "Users", "UserID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

        }           
    }
```

When `ConnectionString` is not a key in app.config, it is supposed to create a database of that name, and initialize it for the user model. The localdb database is created successfully if it doesn't already exist. `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` now fails with

```
`Connection string "testdb" was not found.`
```

While troubleshooting, I tried changing the connection string to use the actual connection sting instead of the alias:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString,
   "Users", "UserID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

This resolves to the full connection string to the localdb server:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\\v11.0;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE'
```

I figured this would at least work. Not so:

```
Connection string "Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE" was not found.
```

Any ideas? This is the first project I've used EF with and so some of it is still a bit mysterious to me. It worked like magic when I first set up the test project, and I can't fathom what might have changed. It seems especially strange that  the initializer won't even work with a real connection string. The actual application still works fine, I just can't get the test project working now.

Comment: I came across numerous problems using WebSecurity and Code First EF. Where is you InitializeSimpleMembership method called from? A controller attribute?

Comment: In the test project, it is called directly from the `[AssemblyInitialize]` test method, e.g. at the start of a test run. I am technically using CodeFirst though I don't let it alter my tables in the actual project - rather, I use it for convenience during testing.

Answer (score 4):

There are two very similar **InitializeDatabaseConnection** methods and that is causing the confusion.

The line:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString,
   "Users", "UserID", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

Is always expecting a connection string name that **must exist** in the appSettings of your config.

To specifically pass in a connection string of your own the **InitializaDatabaseConnection** method requires 6 arguments to be passed in. The extra argument comes second and is the provider name.

Comment: Thanks - that sounds like why my troubleshooting scenario didn't work. But I don't think that the connection string name must exist; previously, if I passed in a non-existent key name, it would assume I was referring to a database of that name on localdb server (creating it first, if it didn't exist, from the prior code block). That part stopped working.

Comment: I think that is EF, not WebSecurity. You can pass in just the name of database if you are using SQL Compact (.sdf) in your app_data folder.